# R - how to avoid repeating filter & row bind

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

Because I am working on a very large dataset, I need to slice my dataset by groups in order to pursue my computations.

I have a person-period (`melt`) dataset that looks like this

```
    group id var time
1      A  1   a    1
2      A  1   b    2
3      A  1   a    3
4      A  2   b    1
5      A  2   b    2
6      A  2   b    3
7      B  1   a    1
8      B  1   a    2
9      B  1   a    3
10     B  2   c    1
11     B  2   c    2
12     B  2   c    3
```

I need to do this simple transformation

```
library(reshape2) 
library(dplyr) 

dt %>% dcast(group + id ~ time, value.var = 'var')
```

In order to get

```
  group id 1 2 3
1     A  1 a b a
2     A  2 b b b
3     B  1 a a a
4     B  2 c c c
```

So far, so good.

However, because my database is too big, I need to do this separately for each different groups, such as

```
a = dt %>% filter(group == 'A') %>% dcast(group + id ~ time, value.var ='var')
b = dt %>% filter(group == 'B') %>% dcast(group + id ~ time, value.var = 'var')

bind_rows(a,b)
```

My problem is that I would like to avoid **doing it by hand**. I mean, having to store separately each groups, `a = ..., b = ..., c = ..., and so on`

Any idea how I could have a single `pipe` stream that would separate each group, compute the transformation and put it back together in a dataframe ?

```
dt = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), var = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "id", 
"var", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package *purrr* can be useful for working with lists.  First split the dataset by group and then use `map_df` to `dcast` each list but return everything in a single data.frame.

```
library(purrr)

dt %>%
    split(.$group) %>%
    map_df(~dcast(.x, group + id ~ time, value.var = "var"))

  group id 1 2 3
1     A  1 a b a
2     A  2 b b b
3     B  1 a a a
4     B  2 c c c
```

Comment: That's a neat solution if you want to use an additional package :)
I'll be sure to put `purrr` on my list of packages-to-check-out.

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` is your friend here:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(dt$Group), function(grp, dt){
  dt %>% filter(Group == grp) %>% dcast(group + id ~ time, value.var = "var")
}, dt = dt))
```